# Is there any eventlog entry that shows the startup programs execution

Tags: windows-8.1, boot, event-log

I am running a selfprogrammed program on startup, or atleast, that is what I want to do. Execution doesn't seem to take place, even the built in logging to textfile does not happen.

The program is added through using a shortcut in the startup folder in appdata. It is recognised in the taskmanager, tab Startup, and says it is enabled. Also, manual starting/execution works perfectly.

Is there any entry in the eventlog (event viewer) which shows the details around startup programs? I have searched both the eventviewer and tried google, but can not seem to find any clues.

Answer (score 0):

By default only services are shown there. An application will be visible in the eventlog application tab if it writes to the eventlog itself.

If you schedule the program to run through task scheduler you can see in the taskscheduler if a program launched and if not, why it didn't.

Comment: That is another weird thing. It works through the taskscheduler, but not as actual startup program.

Comment: Then you have to look into what happens when you launch a program like that. Is it executed with a different user that has no rights to execute the program, is your program dependend on something not accessible by whatever is executing your program because it has no rights or that part has not yet loaded? Also why not just start the program through task scheduler if that does work?

Comment: The program runs under the same user so no problems there. I am copying files to Program Files in that program. But the strange this is, I have added logging at the very start of the program to indicate if it started yes or no. But nothing showed, so it does not get executed at all. And the thing I want to know is why.

Comment: Are you sure the startup folder is actually the correct place? To start programs at launch, you need to point your explorer to `shell:startup` Once you created the shortcut, double click it to test if it launches.

Comment: How do I point my explorer to shell:startup? I am using this folder: AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup. The program gets recognized by the taskmanager (in tab startup).

Comment: Start a `This PC` instance, then in the addressbar type `shell:startup` and press enter.

Comment: Yup. It is the correct location.

Comment: Hmm. I have no clue then. At this point the scope of this question no longer is valid and I recommend creating a new question to get the proper help. Feel free to use parts in this conversation, and then delete the question itself.